# My website only loads after several refreshes

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, nginx

I'm trying to understand why my website only loads on the second or third refresh of the page. Once the assets are cached it loads withing a few seconds otherwise it times-out after taking too long.

I suspect it has something to do with my nginx as it's the part I understand the least in my stack but was often edited. I can't seem to access the error log either.

Is there anything erroneous about my setup?

Here is my default.conf:

```
upstream custodian {
  # The web application.
  server custodian:8000;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name custodian.fund www.custodian.fund;
  root /var/www/letsencrypt;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    default_type "text/plain";

    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://custodian.fund$request_uri;
  }
}
  # All http traffic will get redirected to SSL.
  #return 307 https://$host$request_uri;
#}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.custodian.fund;

  return 301 https://custodian.fund$request_uri;
}

server {
  # "deferred" reduces the number of formalities between the server and client.
  listen 443 default deferred;
  server_name www.custodian.fund;

  # Static asset path, which is read from the custodian container's VOLUME.
  root /custodian/static;

  # Ensure timeouts are equal across browsers and raise the max content-length size.
  keepalive_timeout 60;
  client_max_body_size 5m;

  # SSL goodness.
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  resolver_timeout 5s;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";


  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/custodian.fund.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/custodian.fund.key;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/private/custodian.fund.pem;
 # ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/productionexample.crt;
 # ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/productionexample.key;


  # Disallow access to hidden files and directories.
  location ~ /\. {
    return 404;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  # Allow optionally writing an index.html file to take precedence over the upstream.
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @custodian;

  # Attempt to load the favicon or fall back to status code 204.
  location = /favicon.ico {
    try_files /favicon.ico = 204;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  # Load the web app back end with proper headers.
  location @custodian {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://custodian;
  }
}
```

And this is my nginx.conf:

```
# Number of workers to run, usually equals number of CPU cores.
worker_processes auto;

# Maximum number of opened files per process.
worker_rlimit_nofile 4096;

events {
  # Maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by a worker process.
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Security settings from:
  # https://gist.github.com/plentz/6737338

  # Disable nginx version from being displayed on errors.
  server_tokens off;

  # config to don't allow the browser to render the page inside an frame or iframe
  # and avoid clickjacking http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking
  # if you need to allow [i]frames, you can use SAMEORIGIN or even set an uri with ALLOW-FROM uri
  # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

  # when serving user-supplied content, include a X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff header along with the Content-Type: header,
  # to disable content-type sniffing on some browsers.
  # https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers
  # currently suppoorted in IE > 8 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/02/ie8-security-part-vi-beta-2-update.aspx
  # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622941(v=vs.85).aspx
  # 'soon' on Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471020
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

  # This header enables the Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter built into most recent web browsers.
  # It's usually enabled by default anyway, so the role of this header is to re-enable the filter for
  # this particular website if it was disabled by the user.
  # https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # Avoid situations where a hostname is too long when dealing with vhosts.
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  server_names_hash_max_size 512;

  # Performance optimizations.
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;

  # http://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  # Enable gzip for everything but IE6.
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_types      text/plain application/xml;
  gzip_proxied    no-cache no-store private expired auth;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gunzip on;

  # Default config for the app backend.
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second SSL `server_name` entry just be `custodian.fund` not `www.custodian.fund` (i.e. which is listed twice currently)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Anaksunaman. I tried that but it's still taking a long time to load on the first go. Any other suggestions?